# Перевод байт-кода в двоичное или в число с другим основанием на python

Tags: python, binary, byte, pyserial

ПЛИС измеряет угол поворота вала, и посылает двоичный код по COM-port (uart интерфейс). Я пытаюсь написать программу с gui на python, которая будет принимать двоичный код с ПЛИС и выводить угол поворота вала на графике.

Для приёма данных использую библиотеку pyserial. Данные с com порта принимаются, но выдаются в виде байткода. По типу `b'\x8c'`. Данные передаются 8и битными словами. Я так понимаю `b'\x8c'` это hex число 8c или в двоичном представлении - 10001100, принятое с ПЛИС по ком-порту.

Собственно вопрос. Как этот байт код преобразовать в двоичное число вида `0b10001100` или любой другой системы счисления? Чтобы python воспринимал это число как int, и чтобы с ним можно было производить дальнейшие операции.

Код работы с ком-портом:

```
ser = serial.Serial("COM8", bauderate=115200)
while True:
    line = ser.read()
    print(line)
```

Пишу с телефона и в первый раз задаю вопрос, так что сразу прошу прощения если что-то неправильно оформил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные с порта с помощью `read` принимаются в массив байтов `line`. Если вы делаете `print` этого массива, то по умолчанию он выводится в шестнадцатиричном виде, но само **содержимое не зависит от его представления** - это в любом случае набор байтов.

Нужно использовать отдельные байты - используйте:

```
if len(buf) > 2:    
    checksum = (line[0] + line[1]) & 0xFF
```

А вот коротенький пример - как копить данные, ведь пакет данных не обязан весь за один раз прийти:

```
in_len = 0
sum_len = 0
lst = []
while sum_len < 4:
    buf = ser.read(4)
    in_len = len(buf)
    sum_len += in_len
    print(buf, in_len)
    for i in range(in_len):
       lst.append(buf[i])
    time.sleep(0.1)
print(lst)
```

Comment: print(type(line)) выдает <class 'bytes'>. Я не понимаю как мне производить какие-то действия с этими данными. Например задается x = 0x14, далее x передается в функцию построения графика как аргумент для координат по осям x, y. И на графике строится точка с координатами 20,20. А если x задать, x = b'\x14' программа выдает ошибку could not convert string to float: b'\x14' то есть, то что я получаю с компорта является классом bytes и по всей видимости является строкой. И я не могу на графике отрисовать. И мне надо что бы мои биты принимаемые с компорта были числом, желательно двоичным. Пример 0b1

Comment: @АлександрХалеев line[0] вернет числовое значение первого байта. Если байт несколько, идете циклом по этим байтам (например, `for b in line:`), со значение мкаждого байта что-то делаете.

Comment: Я же пример показал, как  арифметика работает с line[i].  `... и по всей видимости является строкой` нет, вы же сами видите, что это <class 'bytes'>, работайте с ним, как с обычным списком или массивом

Comment: Если что-то не получается, покажите на простом примере, что нужно сделать с данными

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответы!!